# How to set GridViewColumn Cell Template with Style Triggers

Tags: wpf, telerik

At the moment my grid is changing to Autogenerate columns so I cannot predefine the column style. I'm wondering how abouts do I set a style trigger for a column based on header value.

Working code with predefined columns with `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`

```
<telerik:GridViewColumn Header="Test">
    <telerik:GridViewColumn.CellEditTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ToggleDataTemplate">
            <telerik:RadToggleButton Content="+" Width="20" Height="20"
                                     HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                                     VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:GridViewColumn.CellEditTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewColumn>
```

What I've tried with `AutoGenerateColumns="False"`

```
<telerik:RadGridView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="telerik:GridViewColumn">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Header" Value="Test">
                <Setter Property="CellTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ToggleDataTemplate}" />
                <Setter Property="CellEditTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ToggleDataTemplate}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</telerik:RadGridView.Resources>

<DataTemplate x:Key="ToggleDataTemplate">
    <telerik:RadToggleButton Content="+" Width="20" Height="20"
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

With what I tried above, the cell remains blank. How abouts do I get the button to appear dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to handle the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event and set the `CellEditTemplate` of all columns programmatically:

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="grid" AutoGeneratingColumn="grid_AutoGeneratingColumn">
    <telerik:RadGridView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ToggleDataTemplate">
            <telerik:RadToggleButton Content="+" Width="20" Height="20"
                                     HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                                     VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:RadGridView.Resources>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

---

```
private void grid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridViewAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    e.Column.CellEditTemplate = grid.Resources["ToggleDataTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
}
```